# Как найти путь до запущеного бинарника в консольном приложении под windows?

Tags: c++, файлы

... или даже кроссплатформенно ?

Comment: действительно дубликат вопроса. сразу не нашел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetModuleFileName
Если процесс запущен через CreateProcess, аргументы командной строки у него формируются вызывающей стороной и в argv[0] может быть погода на марсе.

Comment: GetModuleFileName - это "кроссплатформенно"?

Comment: Это корректно работает хотя бы в одной операционке.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: При запуске из командной строки там может быть имя без пути.